# Able to modify final value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, final

```
open class OpenBase(open val value: Int)

interface AnotherExample {
    val anotherValue: OpenBase
}

open class OpenChild(value: Int) : OpenBase(value), AnotherExample {
    override var value: Int = 1000
        get() = field - 7
    override val anotherValue: OpenBase = OpenBase(value)
}

open class AnotherChild(value: Int) : OpenChild(value) {
    final override var value: Int = value
        get() = field
        set(value) { field = value * 2 }
    final override val anotherValue: OpenChild = OpenChild(value)
}

fun main() {
    val openChild = OpenChild(42)
    println("OpenChild value: ${openChild.value}")
    println("OpenChild anotherValue: ${openChild.anotherValue.value}")

    val anotherChild = AnotherChild(42)
    println("AnotherChild value: ${anotherChild.value}")
    println("AnotherChild anotherValue: ${anotherChild.anotherValue.value}")
    
    anotherChild.value=69 //HERE
    println("AnotherChild value: ${anotherChild.value}")
    println("AnotherChild anotherValue: ${anotherChild.anotherValue.value}")
}
```

I was learning kotlin OOPS and was playing with an example; I was expecting an error but got no error. Why am I able to modify the value mentioned final?

Comment: You're confusing final and val. Final doesn't mean the variable is const in Kotlin.

Comment: `val` doesn't mean final, const or immutable - it means read-only. It can change, but you can't mutate it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `final` in `final override var value` only means that the property can't be overridden in other subclasses. If want `value` to be read only in `AnotherChild`, you must declare it as `val` instead of `var`. Or, if you do need a private setter, declare it as `var` but add `private` to `set`.

In the context of class members, `val` simply means "property with a getter", and `var` means "property with a getter and a setter`. The latter is a valid override for the former, which is what you are doing in` AnotherChild`.

Comment: I was talking about this ```final override var value: Int = value``` in AnotherChild class